# Two-column slide in R slidy_presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidy

I'm used to making two column slides in R ioslides_presentation documents, but I can't find any method that works to split a slide into two columns using R slidy_presentations which I'm trying for the first time after having used ioslides, beamer, and Rpres.  There must be a way?

Answer (score 5):

It was easier than I realized - taking the column information from the [slidify customization page](http://slidify.org/customize.html), rather than creating a column layout file, simply adding

```
<div class='left' style='float:left;width:48%'>
code or image for left of slide
</div>
<div class='right' style='float:right;width:48%'>
code or image for right
</div>
```

to the slide in my slidy_presentation markdown file worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

May be the following solution is simpler :

```
## Slide with 3 columns (2 or other)

::: columns

:::: {.column width=33%}
left
::::

:::: {.column width=33%}
middle
::::

:::: {.column width=33%}
right
::::

:::
```