# RStudio not rendering two column powerpoint properly

Tags: r, rstudio, powerpoint, pandoc

I'm trying to create a powerpoint presentation using RStudio, closely [following these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-RStudio#columns). Though I'm missing something and the two columns configuration won't work. I'm using `RStudio Server 1.2.5036` on a Ubuntu machine and also this `rmarkdown::pandoc_version() [1] ‘2.3.1’`. The [troubleshooting page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006283914-Troubleshooting-PowerPoint-Output) didn't help me either.

My code is pretty much a copypasta from the tutorial page, but to be sure, here it is:

````
---
title: "something"
author: "me"
date: "01/01/2020"
output:
  ioslides_presentation: default
  slidy_presentation: default
  beamer_presentation: default
  powerpoint_presentation: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("readxl")
my_data <- read_excel("data/my_data.xlsx")
```

## Intro

Loren Ipsun

## About the data

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
```{r summary, echo = FALSE}
summary(my_data)
```
:::
::: {.column}
```{r boxplot, fig.height = 6, fig.width = 4, fig.align = "right"}
boxplot(my_data)
```
:::
::::::::::::::
````

It produces three slides, correct content but the column content shows underneath of each other. Am I missing something obvious?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You have multiple (4) output formats here --- when I tried this with the `powerpoint` and `beamer` (alone) it rendered with 2 columns, but did not with `ioslides` and `slidy`.

Comment: also try updating to `pandoc 2.9`...

Comment: @Ben that did it! Wanna write the answer?

Comment: @mb21 thanks, might actually do that anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 output formats in your Rmd file. If you just include `powerpoint` and/or `beamer` your knitted file should be rendered with two columns as desired.

If you want to use `slidy_presentation` you could do the following:

```
<div class='left' style='float:left;width:48%'>
  code or image for left of slide
</div>
<div class='right' style='float:right;width:48%'>
  code or image for right
</div>
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243552/two-column-slide-in-r-slidy-presentation) or with a custom layout as described [here](http://slidify.org/customize.html).

For `ioslides_presentation`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378349/force-column-break-in-rmarkdown-ioslides-columns-2-layout) which nicely describes forcing a break between two columns with `ioslides`. (And again, you can simply add `html` tags as with the `slidy_presentation` example above.)